# Split maya render layers to files

Tags: scripting, render, maya, mel, pymel

I am trying to make a script in maya to export render layers to separate files. Though I am not clear on the logic to be applied for the script. I dont want any code just the procedure.
Can anyone please help.
Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Why do you want to separate them into separate files? I am asking because there might be a better solution to what you want to achieve than by splitting the file by render layers.

Comment: Actually in the studio I work in has asked me to do so. According to their back of the envelope calculations splitting huge files into layers decreases the render time on muster. Thats all I know about it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense because all Muster is doing is opening Mayabatch with file specific parameters to render. Muster isn't doing the rendering. Also opening and loading up a Maya file each time might actually take more time than to load it up once and cycle through render layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the render layers with

```
cmds.ls(type='renderLayer')
```

and the contents of each layer with

```
cmds.editRenderLayerMembers('layer-name-here', q=True)
```

You'l have to decide for yourself how to deal with objects that exist in multiple layers and so on.